# How to use local docker containers with Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have been trying Kubernetes, I have setup a master and minions in AWS. The documentation on docker + Kubernetes seems to be lacking, or maybe I was looking for it in the wrong place.

Lets say I build my docker containers on a local box (not in AWS). I donot have a docker registry.

Is it possible for me to tell Kubernetes to use my local containers when spinning up pods? Or do my containers need to be put in a docker registry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the image was built on a host where Kubernetes is running, then yes, Kubernetes may use it on some conditions:

- your pod is scheduled on a host where **your image exists** ([pre-built / pre-pulled image](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#pre-pulled-images) scenario)
- your pod *pull policy* is set to `IfNotPresent` (see Updating Images)

Using a private registry would [make your life easier](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry) though, on top of that it's very easy to [set up a local Docker registry](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.9/cluster/addons/registry) with Kubernetes.